# Swift NSTableView Not Reloading Inside Block

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, backendless

I have a very simple Swift project with an NSTableView hooked up in my storyboard. Datasource, delegate and IBOutlet all connected.

The table runs delegate methods when loading, as expected. I could run `tableView.reloadData()` from a `func` and have these methods run again, successfully.

However, I have a method which fetches data and provides a completion block. I call `self.tableView.reloadData()` here but my tableview doesn't reload.

More notably, the app crashes and I see this error in the console: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I reload my tableview from my block?

Also, here is that function:

```
func fetchData()
    {
        beHelper.backendless.data.of(Assembly.ofClass()).find(
            { (collection : BackendlessCollection!) -> Void in

                let assemblies = collection.getCurrentPage()
                self.data.removeAll()
                for obj in assemblies { self.data.append(obj as! Assembly) }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            },
            error: { (fault : Fault!) -> Void in

        })
    }
```

Comment: on which line do you see the `unexpectedly found nil` error ? Also, make sure `reloadData()` is called from the main thread. You can check if it's run on the main thread by adding this line `print("is main thread: \("NSThread.isMainThread()))`

Comment: the crash and error is thrown on the `reloadData` line. I have attempted running it inside `dispatch_async` but get the same result.

Comment: can you check the value of `self.tableView` ? My guess is that it's nil at the point of execution while you declared it as `var tableView : UITableView!` which crashes because it is expected to have a value ?

Comment: The tableview is `nil` at that point. The question becomes, how can I get around this? The table definitely exists at this point in time, but I just can't access it from within the block?

Comment: The real question is, how can you be sure that the tableView exists if it apparently turns out to be nil ? Where are you calling `fetchData()` from ? You should  try calling it in/after `viewDidLoad()` so that you can ensure the `tableView` is in fact in place at that point.